# MySQL database trigger does not work properly

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables, table1 and table2. The SQL is like:

```
create table table1(
  name varchar(100) PRIMARY key not null  
);

create table table2(
  id bigint PRIMARY key AUTO_INCREMENT,
  username varchar(100) not null );
  create trigger trigger_test
  after insert 
  on table1
  for each ROW
    insert into table2 (username)
    select new.name from table1;
```

Every time a row is inserted into table1, this row should also be inserted into table2 by the trigger I created. But after I insert string 'a' into table1, it seems right.

[image: after inserting one row]

After I insert a second string 'b' into table1, the result appears wrong.

[image: after insert two rows].

For the second time, the same row in table2. Then, I keep inserting rows into table1, the third time is like this:

[image: after insert three rows]

I am stuck here because I cannot find a solution. Hope to get your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For each row is a clue your insert clause should be values(new.name).

Comment: How should I modify the sql statement, I don't know how to do it after try several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trigger should be either

```
create trigger trigger_test
after insert 
on table1
for each ROW
    insert into table2 (username)
    values (new.name);
```

Or

```
create trigger trigger_test
after insert 
on table1
for each ROW
    insert into table2 (username)
    select new.name from table1 where name = new.name;
```

Second option is not recomended. But added just to show you where the problem was